# Finding the equation of the tangent

Tags: calculus

I was working on the following question:

> The curve $C$ has equation $y=(x+3)^2$ and the point $A$, with $x$ coordinate $-5$, and lies on $C$.
>
>   $a)$ Find the equation of the tangent line to $C$ at $A$, giving your answer in the form $y= mx+c$
>
>   $b)$ Another point $B$ also lies on $C$. The tangents to $C$ at $A$ and $B$ are parallel. Find the $x$ coordinate of $B$.

$\frac{d}{dx}(x+3)² = 2x+6 \text{ for } x = -5; 2x+6 = -4 = m$

I'm a bit lost :/

Comment: seems okay ,,, just solve $y=-4x + 21$ and $y = (x+3)^2$, it must give only one solution.

Comment: The point of tangency is $(-5,4)$. You probably know how to find the equation of the line through $(-5,4)$ which has slope $-4$.

Comment: I think the way part $b$ is written is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

For part $a$, you're halfway there. You've shown that $m = -4$ so $y = -4x +c$. To find $c$, we need to know a point on the line. All that we know about the line is that it is tangent to the point $A$ on the curve $C$. In particular, the point $A$ lies on the tangent line so we can use its coordinates to determine the value of $c$. So what are the coordinates of $A$? We are told the $x$-coordinate is $-5$, but what about the $y$-coordinate? Well $A$ does not only lie on the tangent line, but also on the curve $C$ which is defined by $y = (x + 3)^2$. Therefore $A$ has $y$-coordinate $y = (-5+3)^2 = (-2)^2 = 4$. So $C$ has coordinates $(-5, 4)$. You can now use this point to determine $c$ (by using the fact that $A$ is on the tangent line so its coordinates satisfy the equation of the tangent line).

For part $b$, use the fact that parallel lines have the same slope and that the slope of the tangent at $B = (x_0, y_0)$ to $C$ is given by $\frac{dy}{dx}(x_0)$. Furthermore, ignore the use of the word 'another' in the question, I think it is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

For part (a):

As you've stated above, $\frac{dy}{dx}=2(x+3)=2x+6$ (by the chain rule). At the point with $x=-5, \frac{dy}{dx}=2(-5)+6=-4$ as you've said too. So the line you're looking for does indeed have $m=-4$.

What you need to do now is work out what $c$ should be. You know that the line $y=mx+c$ passes through $A$, and you can work out $A$'s $y$-coordinate, since it lies on $C$. Any point on the line satisfies $c=y-mx$ so you can work out $c$ in this way.

For part (b):

There is no different point $B$ with tangent to $C$ at $B$ parallel to the tangent to $C$ at $A$:

To say two lines are parallel is equivalent to saying that they have the same slope. So the tangent to $C$ at $B$ has equation $y=mx+d$ (where $d$ is as in (a)). This means that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is the same at $A$ and $B$. So you're looking for another point on C with $\frac{dy}{dx}=-4$, i.e. with $2x+6=-4$. It's $x$-coordinate must also be $-5$. So $y=4$.

This gives the same point $A$ again.

Comment: As Michael has mentioned, the wording in part (b) is misleading. I think the person who wrote the question is trying to emphasise that $B$ _could_ be different from $A$.

Comment: In my opinion, the best way to see that $B$ must have the same $x$-coordinate as $A$ is to notice that the equation for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is linear, so different values of $x$ give different values of $\frac{dy}{dx}$. You can then see that $B$ must _be_ $A$ by noticing from $C$'s equation that given a value of $x$, there is only one possible value for $y$ with $(x,y)$ lying on $C$.

Comment: How would i lay question b out in a numbers equation?

Comment: @John do you mean how would you avoid writing words?

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean.

Comment: I think that if it's clearer to use words than write an equation, then that's what you should do. There's no reason to avoid words in maths. In my opinion it's more important to be clear than very concise using only symbols.

Comment: However, if you really wanted to you could write something like: $\frac{dy}{dx}(B) = \frac{dy}{dx}(A) = -4$. So $2x_B+6=-4$. So $x_B=-5$. This leads to some problems in that you probably need to define what $\frac{dy}{dx}(B)$ and $x_B$ mean.

Comment: I understand what you're saying it is just we are told to give just number answers. Many thanks for your time and effort. Really nice and helpful site, even if I'm not to great with maths!

Comment: @MattGallagher - it may be easier to use $y\prime(B)$ instead of $\frac{dy}{dx}(B)$. Also, if you really wanted to get rid of words completely, you could replace the word "so" with $\implies$

Comment: @Ephraim I think you're probably right that that notation is easier; I'd forgotten that notation even existed! (I haven't done calculus for a while...) You could use $\Longrightarrow$, but I'd be cautious- the statements $p\Longrightarrow (q \Longrightarrow r)$ and $(p\Longrightarrow q) \Longrightarrow r$ are logically different. This means that to be unambiguous when using a chain of $\Longrightarrow$, you should include some brackets. Having said that, I think in a lot of cases (including this one) it is usually clear what is meant if a small chain of $\Longrightarrow$ is used

Answer (score 0):

The slope of the tangent line, at $A$ is equal to $y\prime(-5)$. Then you can just plug that back into the equation $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ and solve for $y$.
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x+3)^2 = 2(x+3) = 2x + 6 \implies y\prime(-5) = -10+6 = -4$$
$$y-y(-5) =y\prime(-5)(x+5)$$
$$y-4 = -4(x+5) \implies y-4=-4x-20$$
$$\boxed{y=-4x-16}$$

For part b, you have to find another point where the slope of the graph is $-4$, and therefore where $y\prime(x) = -4$
$$y\prime(x) = -4 \implies 2x+6 = -4 \implies 2x = -10 \implies x=-5$$

Therefore the only $x$ where the tangent has a slope of $-4$ is at $x=-5$. This means that in order to have a line tangent to $C$, and parallel to $A$, it must *equal* to $A$. This is why the word "another" is misleading, since there isn't a tangent line parallel to $A$ with different different $x$ and $y$ values where it is tangent to $C$.

Therefore, $B=A= (-5, 2)$ so the $x$ coordinate of the point is $-5$.